# Determining the probability of choosing an arrangement of letters when the first letter is fixed but occurs more than once?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability of choosing an arrangement of letters of the word
WOOLLOONGABBA at random, which starts with A and ends in N?

My problem is that the 'A' is fixed in the first position but it happens more than once.

The total arrangement is $\frac{13!}{2!2!2!2!2!}$, after fixing A and N in the firxt and last position, I have 'WOOLLOOGBB' left, so 10 characters. So can I do: $\frac{10!}{2!2!2!2!2!}$, I still divided an extra 2! to account for that there are 2 As in the word?

Is this right?

Comment: You made a mistake. The number of total arrangements is $\frac{13!}{1!4!2!1!1!2!2!}$. Here the numbers in the denominator correspond with the W,O,L,N,G,A,B respectively. If one A and one N are fixed then we get $\frac{11!}{1!4!2!0!1!1!2!}$ arrangements. Note that the number corresponding with A and N are diminished with $1$.

Comment: Your count of total arrangements seems off. There are 4 'O's. After that, to count "successful" strings, you still need to include the other 'A' (there should be 11 characters in the string, not 10).

Comment: Hint on more easy solution (avoiding counting of arrangements): First choose a letter to be the utmost left and then choose a letter to be the utmost right. What is the probability that the first chosen is A and the second chosen is N?....

Comment: A question from Queensland!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your comment made me curious and pushed me to google [Woolloongabba](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woolloongabba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.

The number of different "words" without fixing letters is $\frac{13!}{2!2!2!4!}$, as four Os is not the same as two Os twice. If you fix A and N you would have $\frac{11!}{2!2!4!}$ as there is one other A which can be anywhere. Dividing these gives $\frac{11!/(2!2!4!)}{13!/2!2!2!4!)}=\frac{2}{13\times12}=\frac{1}{78}$ as your answer.

I think the following approach is easier. Suppose first that you have made WOOLLOONGABBA using Scrabble tiles.  Think W O1 O2 L1 L2 O3 O4 N G A1 B1 B2 A2. There are $13!$ equally likely ways to draw the tiles. For strings A1, ..., N there are ${11!}$, and likewise for strings A2, ..., N. So your answer would be $\frac{2\times 11!}{13!}=\frac{1}{78}$, which is the same as above.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer of the arrangements is not correct. The extra $A$ has gone unaccounted.

In any case, the question asks for the *probability*, not the arrangements, and there is a much simpler way to compute the required probability.

P(A first and N last) = P(A first)(P(N last|A first)

$= \Large\frac2{13}\frac1{12} = \frac1{78}$

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to count arrangements.  Each of the $13$ letters is equally likely to be first, so the probability that the first letter is A is $\frac{2}{13}$.  If the first letter is an A, the N is equally likely to end up in any of the remaining $12$ slots, so the probability the last letter is N, assuming the first letter is A, is $\frac{1}{12}$.

Thus, the probability that both conditions are satisfied is $\frac{2}{13} \cdot \frac {1}{12}=\frac{1}{78}$.